# Ngrok inbuilt file server configuration through config file

Tags: ngrok

Ngrok servers a folder using inbuild server when we run the following in command line

```
    ngrok http file://<path to file>
```

I am trying to configure more tunnels like ssh in the same machine using config files like

```
    tunnels:
      httpbin:
        proto: http
        file: "//<path to file>" ##THIS IS ERROR ##
      demo:
        proto: ssh
        addr: 22
```

is does not seems to be possible to configure inbuild file sharing using a configuration file in ngrok. Or is there some way?

Answer (score 1):

You try this steps:

1. https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken and login
2. Terminal and run: `ngrok authtoken token_id`
   result:  `Authtoken saved to configuration file: /home/user/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml`
3. Terminal: `ngrok http file:///home`
4. Finish !

result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPZbP.png

ngrok doc: https://ngrok.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

Actually just stumbled across it by accident. A bit of experimentation, and no guarantees that it will continue to work since it's not mentioned in the docs. Just use the `file:` protocol in the `addr` yaml option.

```yaml
authtoken: <REDACTED>
tunnels:
  dev2:
    proto: http
    addr: file:///some/path/just/like/command/line
    hostname: my-great-subdomain.ngrok.io
```